# Does Crashreport.net have any configurations in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crash-reports

I implemented a crash report using Crashreport.net in my application in vb.net that sends an Email including the crash log and the name of the form in my program in which the crash has happend. I would like to know if there is any method to get to know the location of the crash? I mean while it specifies the name of the form , i would like to know the name of the function in which the crash has happened as well. Is there any option that needs to be checked in CrashReport.net to enable that or any other parameter modifications?

Comment: Sounds like something that would be explained in the documentation.

Comment: I couldn't find a good documentation :( even on the internet )

Comment: Check the library metadata then, see if there are any giveaways in there.

Comment: Thanks buddy :) .